# need quick fix to sql errors

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

I'm having problems with this block of code, the error is: String or binary data would be truncated

```
    Protected Sub FormView1_ItemInserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewInsertEventArgs) Handles FormView1.ItemInserting
    Using cnnentry As New SqlConnection("Data Source=NB-1492\sqlipt;Initial Catalog=Bookings;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")
        Dim entrclientid As String
        Dim clid As New TextBox
        clid = FormView1.FindControl("txtclientid")
        entrclientid = clid.Text
        Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO BOOKING_DETAILS(CLIENT_ID,BOOKING_DATE,REGO,CHECK_IN_DATE,CHECK_OUT_DATE,ROOM_ID) VALUES(@ROOM_ID,@CHECK_OUT_DATE,@CHECK_IN_DATE,@CLIENT_ID,@BOOKING_DATE,@REGO)"
        Dim cmdentry As New SqlCommand(sql, cnnentry)
        cmdentry.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CLIENT_ID", clid.Text)

        Dim curdate As New TextBox
        curdate = FormView1.FindControl("txtdate")
        cmdentry.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BOOKING_DATE", curdate.Text)

        Dim rego As New TextBox
        rego = FormView1.FindControl("RegoTextBox")
        cmdentry.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REGO", rego.Text)

        Dim textin As New TextBox
        textin = FormView1.FindControl("textcheckin")
        cmdentry.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CHECK_IN_DATE", textin.Text)

        Dim textout As New TextBox
        textout = FormView1.FindControl("textcheckout")
        cmdentry.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CHECK_OUT_DATE", textout.Text)

        Dim txtroomid As New TextBox
        txtroomid = Session.Item("room_tpe")
        cmdentry.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROOM_ID", roomtype.Text)

        cnnentry.Open()
        strclid = cmdentry.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cnnentry.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

can somebody explain why i am getting this error?

the table data types are as follows:
Booking_ID            int
Room_ID           int
Check_In_Date   nvarchar(MAX)
Check_Out_Date  nvarchar(MAX)
Booking_Date    nvarchar(MAX)
Client_ID             nchar(11) 
Rego              nvarchar(6)
Room_Cost             money

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which SQL Tool are you using? mysql? sql server 2008 or else?

Comment: Can you run a trace and post the SQL executed? It looks like the data you are trying to insert is too large for the field.

Comment: Why would a booking date be type nvarchar(MAX) and not a Date?  Same question for check in and check out dates.

Comment: You'll need to validate the length (or truncate) the supplied `txtclientid` and `RegoTextBox` fields before blindly inserting them into the DB. Also, using NVARCHAR(MAX) as storage for a date isn't really a good idea - why not use a relevant SQL Date type?

Comment: the booking date is nvarchar because it won't enter into the database in any other way

Comment: I suspect it's your REGO field. Check the data isn't longer than 6 chars.

Comment: What database?  You must be using a really old version of SQL Server: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-the-date-data-type-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: @StuartLC how do you validate the fields?

Comment: no the rego field is fine @bukko i changed it to max and i still got the same error

Comment: CLIENT_ID then? It'll be something like that. Hard to tell without seeing the data or the SQL from a trace.

Comment: Validation : Start here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kh55542(v=vs.100).aspx. Asp.Net Calendar Control (which spits out a strongly typed `DateTime` suitable for binding to a SQL DATE or simlar type like so: `<asp:Calendar runat="server" />`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert data to a field which can not be held by defined datatype. 
E.g : VARCHAR(3) can not hold 'TestData'.

In the table BOOKING_DETAILS check column datatypes.